# The aiogram library with the pip3 package manager is not installed

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp, aiogram

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to install the `aiogram3` library on MacOS Ventura using Python 3.12. During the installation, a compilation error occurs specifically while building one of its dependencies, `aiohttp`.

**Environment Details:**

- OS: MacOS Ventura
- Python Version: 3.12
- Library: aiogram3 (facing issue with aiohttp during installation)

**Log File:**

```
Collecting aiogram
  Obtaining dependency information for aiogram from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/f4/a18f30e7550e96259a71fc5d4b6d24c76d933b0f66c920dba
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
...
...
  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [188 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/worker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/multipart.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_response.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      ...
...
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/gorsenkovegor/Projects/Programming/YMusicBot_for_Alis/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c aiohttp/_websocket.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/_websocket.o
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1475:17: warning: 'Py_OptimizeFlag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       1475 |   if (unlikely(!Py_OptimizeFlag)) {
            |                 ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/pydebug.h:13:1: note: 'Py_OptimizeFlag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
         13 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) PyAPI_DATA(int) Py_OptimizeFlag;
            | ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2680:27: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       2680 |     return likely(dict) ? __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict) : 0;
            |                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
       1118 | #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
            |                                                                 ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
         22 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
            |     ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2692:36: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       2692 |     return (dictptr && *dictptr) ? __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(*dictptr) : 0;
            |                                    ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
       1118 | #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
            |                                                                 ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
         22 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
            |     ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2696:56: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       2696 |     if (unlikely(!dict) || unlikely(tp_dict_version != __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)))
            |                                                        ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
       1118 | #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
            |                                                                 ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
         22 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
            |     ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2741:9: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       2741 |         __PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED(
            |         ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1125:16: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED'
       1125 |     if (likely(__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(DICT) == __pyx_dict_version)) {\
            |                ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
       1118 | #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
            |                                                                 ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
         22 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
            |     ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2741:9: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       2741 |         __PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED(
            |         ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1129:30: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED'
       1129 |         __pyx_dict_version = __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(DICT);\
            |                              ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
       1118 | #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
            |                                                                 ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
         22 |     Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
            |     ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3042:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
       3042 |             const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3097:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
       3097 |             const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3238:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
       3238 |             const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3293:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
       3293 |             const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
            |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3744:47: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
       3744 |     const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)b)->ob_digit;
            |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      6 warnings and 5 errors generated.
      error: command '/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [200 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      copying multidict/_multidict_py.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      copying multidict/_abc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      copying multidict/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      copying multidict/_multidict_base.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      copying multidict/_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      running egg_info
      writing multidict.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/_multidict.html'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.so'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict/*.pyd'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      /private/var/folders/32/n56dkfsj08v_h743fm4mb7y80000gn/T/pip-build-env-5g3zisbi/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py:204: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying multidict/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      copying multidict/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/gorsenkovegor/Projects/Programming/YMusicBot_for_Alis/.venv/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c multidict/_multidict.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/multidict/_multidict.o -O2 -std=c99 -Wall -Wsign-compare -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing -pedantic
      In file included from multidict/_multidict.c:9:
      multidict/_multilib/iter.h:225:20: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
        225 | multidict_iter_init()
            |                    ^
            |                     void
      In file included from multidict/_multidict.c:10:
      multidict/_multilib/views.h:388:21: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
        388 | multidict_views_init()
            |                     ^
            |                      void
      multidict/_multidict.c:458:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        458 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "getall", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:458:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        458 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "getall", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:458:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[7]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        458 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "getall", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:503:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        503 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "getone", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:503:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        503 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "getone", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:503:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[7]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        503 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "getone", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:538:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        538 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "get", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:538:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        538 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "get", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:538:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[4]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        538 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "get", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:712:5: warning: 'UsingDeprecatedTrashcanMacro' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        712 |     Py_TRASHCAN_SAFE_BEGIN(self);
            |     ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/object.h:551:9: note: expanded from macro 'Py_TRASHCAN_SAFE_BEGIN'
        551 |         UsingDeprecatedTrashcanMacro cond=1; \
            |         ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/object.h:548:1: note: 'UsingDeprecatedTrashcanMacro' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        548 | Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) typedef int UsingDeprecatedTrashcanMacro;
            | ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
        317 | #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
            |                                                      ^
      multidict/_multidict.c:780:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        780 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "add", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:780:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        780 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "add", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:780:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[4]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        780 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "add", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:839:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        839 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "setdefault", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:839:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        839 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "setdefault", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:839:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[11]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        839 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "setdefault", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:875:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        875 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "popone", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:875:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        875 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "popone", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:875:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[7]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        875 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "popone", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:922:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        922 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "pop", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:922:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        922 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "pop", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:922:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[4]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        922 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "pop", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:970:37: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
        970 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "popall", 0};
            |                                     ^~~~
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.2/lib/clang/17/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
         89 | #  define NULL ((void*)0)
            |                ^~~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:970:43: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *' with an expression of type 'const char *const[3]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        970 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "popall", 0};
            |                                           ^~~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:970:54: warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'const char *const *' with an expression of type 'char[7]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        970 |     static _PyArg_Parser _parser = {NULL, _keywords, "popall", 0};
            |                                                      ^~~~~~~~
      multidict/_multidict.c:1684:18: warning: a function declaration without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C [-Wstrict-prototypes]
       1684 | PyInit__multidict()
            |                  ^
            |                   void
      20 warnings and 8 errors generated.
      error: command '/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build aiohttp multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

- I tried installing older versions of `aiohttp` and `aiogram3` without success.
- Updated LLVM

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not, I'm writing on python version 3.11